# What is the difference between clc and clear all in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and was going through some machine learning projects written in MATLAB. Some files start with the following lines:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
```

I understand that these lines together render a clean work space. Also, that `close all` is used to close all figures.

If both the `clear all` and `clc` are used to clear command window, then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: just a note. matlab suggests using clear instead of clear all as clear all might be unnecessary and reduce performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `help` for both are quite thorough.

In short:

`clc` - clears the command window

`clear all`  clears variables, but it also clears a lot of other things from memory, such as breakpoints, persistent variables and cached memory - as your new to Matlab this is probably a bit unclear.

In short: You rarely need to use `clear all` - most of the time a simple `clear` will be enough.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep the help handy next time. 
The `clear all` documentation says it 'resets the MuPAD engine' ... what is that?

Comment: mupad is part of the `symbolic toolbox` - (which I dont have) - but in essense `clear all` is clearing all of the memory related to this - so it will take longer to startup/use than if you only did `clear` - this is what I was getting at by saying it clears `cached memory`

Answer (score 5):

No, both are not same. There's a difference.

> **clear all** is basically used to clear/delete the variables created in **Workspace**.
>
> **clc** is basically used to clear the **Command Window** (where we execute MATLAB commands).
>
> ---

#### » clc

It clears Command Window.

> **clc** clears all input and output from the Command Window display, giving you a "clean screen".
>
> After using **clc**, you cannot use the scroll bar to see the history of functions, but you still can use the up arrow key, ↑, to recall statements from the command history.
>
> [Reference link to read more about clc command](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clc.html).

#### » clear

It removes items from workspace, freeing up system memory.

> **clear** removes all variables from the current workspace, releasing them from system memory.
>
> [Reference link to read more about clear command](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html).

#### » clear all

It clears Variable in scope, Scripts and functions, Persistent variables, MEX functions, Global variables etc.

> **Note:** Calling **clear all** decreases code performance, and is usually unnecessary. For more information, see the Tips section.
>
> [Reference link to read more about clear all command](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html).

#### » close

- It removes specified figure.
- It deletes the current figure or the specified figure(s). It optionally returns the status of the close operation.
- It deletes the current figure (equivalent to close(gcf)).

> [Reference link to read more about close command](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html).

#### » close all

It deletes all figures whose handles are not hidden.

> [Reference link to read more about close all command](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
clc
```

clean command window. After this function, all previous command written on window will clean.

```
 clear all
```

this build in function clear all variable created in work space of matlab.

```
clear a
```

This will clear only  variable a from work space